# How to detect if a program is not run from a terminal

Tags: terminal

If I am running a reverse TCP shell and attempt to run su, I get the following message:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

I would like to emulate this behavior in my own program and am wondering how do I detect if a program is being run from a terminal?

Comment: Call `isatty` with `STDIN`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a shell script:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  echo stdin is a terminal
fi
```

In a `perl` script:

```
print "stdin is a terminal\n" if -t;
```

In C:

```
if (isatty(0)) puts("stdin is a terminal");
```

They all do the same, do a tty specific `ioctl` and return true unless the `ioctl` fails with a ENOTTY error. On my system, the `ioctl` is TCGETS and I believe it's fairly common as it's an obvious one.

```
$ : | strace -e ioctl su
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7ffff32dfc50) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
su: must be run from a terminal
```

Comment: Regarding the C solution, it's fine, but don't use puts() and friends. The printf() family is recommended.

Comment: @schaiba, Why? Even `gcc` optimises `printf("stdin is a terminal\n")` to `puts("stdin is a terminal")` even without any `-O` flag.